# How to compare two sets

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get all `aid`'s values which have `cid` != 40 and `cid`= 39 (many-to-many connection)

I've prepared two queries but i don't know how to except second from first

```
SELECT DISTINCT aid FROM ac_branch WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM ac_branch WHERE cid = 39);

SELECT DISTINCT aid FROM ac_branch WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM ac_branch WHERE cid != 40);
```

[image]

Comment: result of the second will contain result of the first. why do you need two of them at the same time

Comment: I've added pic. I need to get `aid` =`64` and `aid` =`23` because they have `39` and don't have `40` but except another `aid`'s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're actually pretty close, is this what you're looking for?

```
SELECT DISTINCT aid 
FROM ac_branch 
WHERE cid = 39 
   AND aid NOT IN (SELECT aid FROM ac_branch WHERE cid = 40)
;
```

---

Alternatively, you can do it without subqueries like so:

```
SELECT aid 
FROM ac_branch
WHERE cid IN (39, 40)
GROUP BY aid
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN cid=39 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) = 1
;
```

Though, this assumes there can only be single entries for 39 and 40 for a given aid value. For example if there were two entries with aid=1 and cid=39, and none with cid=4, aid=1 would not appear (because the sum would be 2). Similarly, an aid with two 39's and one 40 would also be included in the results.

---

A third option involves a JOIN

```
SELECT DISTINCT acb39.aid
FROM ac_branch AS acb39
LEFT JOIN ac_branch AS acb40
   ON acb39.aid = acb40.aid AND acb40.cid = 40
WHERE acb1.cid = 39
   AND acb40.aid IS NULL
;
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way uses aggregation:

```
SELECT aid
FROM ac_branch
WHERE cid IN (39, 40)          -- consider both
GROUP BY aid
HAVING SUM(cid = 39) > 0 AND   -- has 39
       SUM(cid = 40) = 0;      -- does not have 39
```

Because a row has to match and there is no row for `40`, the first condition is redundant, but I would keep it in anyway for clarity.

Comment: Actually `SUM(cid = 39) > 0` is redundant - Though I'd probably still keep it for clearness.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do

```
SELECT aid
FROM ac_branch 
WHERE cid IN (39, 40)
GROUP BY aid
HAVING AVG(cid<>40) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

merge both queries in one query. you ll get result.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT aid FROM ac_branch WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM ac_branch WHERE cid = 39 and cid!=40);
```

Comment: That is just going to get all where `cid=39`, when cid is 39 it cannot also be 40 (for the same record).